# python output to a text file

Tags: python, formatting, tabular

I need to output the values that I calculate from my code to a text file in a certain format. First I will explain how my output from the python code look like and then explain how I want the text file to be.

```
Column A
1
2
3
4
Column B
3
4
1
9
Column C
20
56
89
54
```

How I want the text file is as below

```
Number    Column A    Column B     Column C
0         1           3            20
1         2           4            56
2         3           1            89
3         4           9            54
```

all the output on the screen are due to print statement of variable value that I am calculating using the code. Can you help me on how I can do this?

Comment: Show us what you tried yourself and what your problem with that is.

Comment: @IrmendeJong meant: post your code.

Comment: Try to print the first line.

Comment: My code is 200 lines long. Is it possible to attach it?

Comment: Maybe you could add it to a gist and share the link: https://gist.github.com/

Comment: Even better, construct a [mcve] that reproduces this behavior and try to make it work with that, then if you can't figure it out ask using the example code. I'm guessing that most of those 200 lines have nothing to do with this output formatting question.

Answer (score 1):

If the items come in that order you will have to save it to a list, dictionary or something and then print. Look at this example:

```
output = [[] for i in range(5)] # [[],[],[],[],[]]

for ind, item in enumerate(["Column A","1","2","3","4"]):
    print(item)
    output[ind].append(item)    

for ind, item in enumerate(["Column B","3","4","1","9"]):
    print(item)
    output[ind].append(item)

with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
    for row in output:
        f.write('\t'.join(row))
        f.write('\n')
```

prints:

```
Column A
1
2
3
4
Column B
3
4
1
9
```

Output:

```
[['Column A', 'Column B'], ['1', '3'], ['2', '4'], ['3', '1'], ['4', '9']]
```

"output.txt":

```
Column A    Column B
1   3
2   4
3   1
4   9
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `print()` statement that already does exactly what you want then you only have to redirect the output to a textfile.

```
with open(r'path_to\my_file.txt','w') as textfile:
    ... your existing code goes here ...
    ...
    print ( ... whatever your print statement does ..., file=textfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `print` statement is creating that output exactly the way you want, I strongly suggest using the new-ish [`pathlib` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) (available in Python >= 3.4) to create your file. It is great for working with path-like objects (both Windows and for other OSes).

If your file content is stored as a string in `data`, you can just do this:

```
from pathlib import Path

file_path = Path('some_file.txt') # a relative file path - points within current directory
file_path.write_text(data) # overwrites existing file of same name
file_path.write_text(data, mode='a') # appends to an existing file of same name
```

Here's a little `Path` tutorial.

### [It's Paths - Paths all the way down](https://xkcd.com/1416/)

To simplify: you can build up any path (directory and file path objects are treated exactly the same) as an object, which can be an *absolute path object* or a *relative path object*.

Simple displaying of some useful paths- such as the current working directory and the user home- works like this:

```
from pathlib import Path

# Current directory (relative):
cwd = Path() # or Path('.')
print(cwd)

# Current directory (absolute):
cwd = Path.cwd()
print(cwd)

# User home directory:
home = Path.home()
print(home)

# Something inside the current directory
file_path = Path('some_file.txt') # relative path; or 
file_path = Path()/'some_file.txt' # also relative path
file_path = Path().resolve()/Path('some_file.txt') # absolute path
print(file_path)
```

To navigate down the file tree, you can do things like this. Note that the first object, `home`, is a `Path` and the rest are just strings:

```
file_path = home/'Documents'/'project'/'data.txt' # or
file_path = home.join('Documents', 'project', 'data.txt')
```

To read a file located at a path, you can use its `open` method rather than the `open` function:

```
with file_path.open() as f:
    dostuff(f)
```

But you can also just grab the text directly!

```
contents = file_path.read_text()
content_lines = contents.split('\n')
```

...and WRITE text directly!

```
data = '\n'.join(content_lines)
file_path.write_text(data) # overwrites existing file
```

Check to see if it is a file or a directory (and exists) this way:

```
file_path.is_dir() # False
file_path.is_file() # True
```

Make a new, empty file without opening it like this (silently replaces any existing file):

```
file_path.touch()
```

To make the file *only if it doesn't exist*, use `exist_ok=False`:

```
try:
    file_path.touch(exist_ok=False)
except FileExistsError:
    # file exists
```

Make a new directory (under the current directory, `Path()`) like this:

```
Path().mkdir('new/dir') # get errors if Path()/`new` doesn't exist
Path().mkdir('new/dir', parents=True) # will make Path()/`new` if it doesn't exist
Path().mkdir('new/dir', exist_ok=True) # errors ignored if `dir` already exists
```

Get the file extension or filename of a path this way:

```
file_path.suffix # empty string if no extension
file_path.stem # note: works on directories too
```

Use `name` for the entire last part of the path (stem and extension if they are there):

```
file_path.name # note: works on directories too
```

Rename a file using the `with_name` method (which returns the same path object but with a new filename):

```
new_path = file_path.with_name('data.txt')
```

You can iterate through all the "stuff' in a directory like so using `iterdir`:

```
all_the_things = list(Path().iterdir()) # returns a list of Path objects
```

Comment: While this is kind of interesting, it is not really relevant for solving the problem in the question.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I disagree. The OP wanted to know how to write data to a file. That's the first thing I show how to do. My intention here is to "sell" the OP on using the `pathlib` module for future problems as well, because it is awesome and will save OP a ton of trouble. `pathlib` is still fairly new and most people don't seem to know about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.savetxt` and use the header-keyword

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html

Answer (score 0):

I searched and found that it was better for me to print the values in the terminal exactly like how I want in the text file. So I rewrote my code to display the values as one complete tab limited row and it worked. I appreciate all your help.
I am not sure if this can be marked as an answer. If not let me know, I will add as a comment.