# Importing a big txt file into Python and creating a list of lists

Tags: python, list, import

I've got a big txt file. Each line looks like this:

```
1. 27.01.1957 8,12,31,39,43,45  
2. 03.02.1957 5,10,11,22,25,27  
3. 10.02.1957 18,19,20,26,45,49  
4. 17.02.1957 2,11,14,37,40,45  
5. 24.02.1957 8,10,15,35,39,49  
6. 03.03.1957 24,26,31,35,43,47  
7. 10.03.1957 13,20,23,29,38,44
```

I would like to to create a list of list which one line in each list.
How can I do it?

Comment: What form should the `list` of `list`s take? Three elements per line? More? Less? The input you give could validly produce many different outputs.

Answer (score 2):

If the file is truly *big*, you might want to use a generator to keep memory usage down:

```
def read_lines_from_big_file(path):
    with open(path) as fp:
        for line in fp:
            parts = line.split()
            yield parts  # -> ['1.', '27.01.1957', '8,12,31,39,43,45']

for split_line in read_lines_from_big_file(path):
    # do something with split_line
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a lists of lists where each sublist is literally a string that represents each of your file lines you can do this:

```
data = [];
with open("big_file.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line  in f:
        data.append([line.strip()])
```

Here the program reads the file line by line and appends each line from the file as a sublist to the list `data`.

Alternatively, if you want to have each space-separated element in the sublist as a separate element, use `split()` in the appending line instead,

```
data.append(line.split())
```

which will split the components by spaces - remove the extra `[]` too as `split()` will return sublists anyway.

Comment: `.strip().split()` is redundant; `.split()` (with no arguments only) already ignores leading and trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own delimiters to split your strings by (or file lines in this case) with the module `re` https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html. Using `with open()` means that the file link is closed after the `with open()` indent in your code has ended.

I use `list comprehension` here because it's slightly faster than a for loop to construct lists

```
import re

def return_lines_split_by_choice(delimiters,path):
    re_pattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape,delimiters))
    with open(path) as file_handle:
        return [re.split(re_pattern,line.rstrip()) for line in file_handle]

my_list_of_lists = return_lines_split_by_choice((" ",","),my_filepath)
```

Just put your choice of delimiters, or things to split the lines by in here `(" ",",")`

The result is:

```
for sublist in my_list_of_lists:
    print (sublist)

['1.', '27.01.1957', '8', '12', '31', '39', '43', '45']
['2.', '03.02.1957', '5', '10', '11', '22', '25', '27']
['3.', '10.02.1957', '18', '19', '20', '26', '45', '49']
['4.', '17.02.1957', '2', '11', '14', '37', '40', '45']
['5.', '24.02.1957', '8', '10', '15', '35', '39', '49']
['6.', '03.03.1957', '24', '26', '31', '35', '43', '47']
['7.', '10.03.1957', '13', '20', '23', '29', '38', '44']
```

If you just want a list of lines use this function instead:

```
def list_of_lines(path):
    with open(path) as file_handle:
        return [line.rstrip() for line in file_handle]
```

Just run it like this:

```
my_list_of_lists = list_of_lines(my_filepath)
```

If your python program is in the same folder as your txt file then your filepath can just be the name of the file like so `"mytxt.txt"` else you can use the `os` module to normalize a filepath for your operating system

Answer (score -2):

Learn to make your life much easier and don't use `with open`. Instead, [learn to use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45464707/2437514) the awesome [`pathlib` package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html).

Using the `pathlib.Path.read_text()` method, you can load your file into a list of strings, each of which is a line:

```
import pathlib

text = pathlib.Path('myfile.txt').read_text()
```

To make that into into a list of lines, use the `split` method, splitting at each line break:

```
lines = text.split('\n')
```

Almost there. Now you want to make your list of lists. I am a assuming you want each sublist to be made up of the things between the spaces and the commas. With that in mind, construct your list of lists like this:

```
listoflists = []
for line in lines:
    listoflists.append(line.replace(',', ' ').split())
```

Finally, do it all in one go as follows:

```
listoflists = [line.replace(",", " ").split() for line in pathlib.Path('myfile.txt').read_text().split("\n")]
```

Comment: That doesn't seem easier than using `with` to me. Plus it reads the whole file in at once, which might not be suitable if the file is really big.

Comment: @Wyatt irrelevant in this case. The entire file is going to be read into memory anyway. Might as well do it right away. My point here is to evangelize `pathlib` to a new user a bit, because it is SO MUCH BETTER than every other way of handling text and files.

Comment: It's possible to avoid reading the whole file by using a generator. I agree that for simple cases (and relatively small amounts of data) `Path.read_text()` might be easier, but not in every case.